# ubuntu reboot issue-connection closed by remote host

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, reboot

Whenever I use `sudo reboot`, `sudo shutdown -Hr now` etc it says `connection closed by remote host`. I have tried almost every command which is present on net.  I am using ubuntu 20.04 on raspberry pi3.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what is supposed to happen.  Are you connecting to the system via ssh?

Comment: yes, my system is connected via putty

Answer (score 0):

When you reboot a machine you are turning the operating system off.  At that point it will terminate all running services and will be no longer able to maintain a secure shell connection (or pretty much any connection really), so you will receive the "connection closed by remote host" error.

You should be able to reconnect when the operating system is finished starting back up.

Comment: actually i just want my program to run as a autorun, for this i need system to reboot after give my file location to bashrc. but, nothing works, well, thanks for your concern sir